# I want to add plotbands in rectangle formed after plotting four lines in highchart marked in red line

Tags: highcharts

[Image of Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuHv9.png)I've plotted the highchart and line dynamically in mine application,
but now I need to put `plotBands` in rectangle only formed after inserting the lines.
I'm not able to get inserting points of those lines and to `plotbands` in that rectangle.

I've mentioned mine code while rendering graphs and plotting line below.

```
     chart: {
         type: 'scatter', 
         zoomType: 'xy',
     },
        title: {text: 'Project Cost Vs Project Schedule Chart'},
        subtitle: {text: '', style: {display: 'none'}},
        xAxis: [{
            min:minX,
            crosshair: true,
            title: {
                text: 'Cost',
                style:{fontWeight: 'normal'}
             },
             labels: {                         
                    style:{fontWeight: 'normal'}
                },
                plotLines: [{ 
                    color: '#D3D3D3', // Color value 
                    dashStyle: 'black', // Style of the plot line. Default to solid
                    value: avgCost, // Value of where the line will appear
                    width: 2 // Width of the line    
                  },
                  {
                    color: '#7CB5EC', // Color value
                    dashStyle: 'Dash', // Style of the plot line. Default to solid
                    value: lowerBoundCost, // Value of where the line will appear
                    width: 2 // Width of the line    
                      },
                      {
                            color: '#7CB5EC', // Color value
                            dashStyle: 'Dash', // Style of the plot line. Default to solid
                            value: upperBoundCost, // Value of where the line will appear
                            width: 2 // Width of the line    
                              }]
        }],
        yAxis: [{
            min:minY,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Schedule(days)',
               style:{fontWeight: 'normal'}
            },
            labels: {
                 format: '{value}',
                style:{fontWeight: 'normal'}
            },
            plotLines: [{
                color: '#D3D3D3', // Color value
                dashStyle: 'black', // Style of the plot line. Default to solid
                value: avgSchedule, // Value of where the line will appear
                width: 2 // Width of the line    
              },
              {
                color: '#7CB5EC', // Color value
                dashStyle: 'Dash', // Style of the plot line. Default to solid
                value: lowerBoundSchedule, // Value of where the line will appear
                width: 2 // Width of the line    
                  },
                  {
                        color: '#7CB5EC', // Color value
                        dashStyle: 'Dash', // Style of the plot line. Default to solid
                        value: upperBoundSchedule, // Value of where the line will appear
                        width: 2 // Width of the line    
                          }],
                          plotBands: [{
                                color: 'rgba(102, 133, 194, 0.298039)', // Color value
                                from: lowerBoundSchedule, // Start of the plot band
                                to:upperBoundSchedule // End of the plot band
                              }],
        }],        
        legend: {
               itemStyle: {fontSize:'13px'},
               symbolRadius: 6,
               symbolWidth: 13,
               symbolHeight: 13,
               enabled: true,
               align: 'right',
               useHTML: true,
               labelFormatter: function() {
                   return '<div style="float:left;text-align:left;font-weight:normal;">' + this.name + '</div>';
                },          
           },               
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true,     
            formatter:function(){
                return  this.point.name + '<br>Cost:' + this.point.x + '$ <br>Schedule:' + this.point.y+'days' ;
            }
        },        
        credits: {enabled: false},           
        exporting: { enabled: false },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                marker: {
                    states: {                           
                        select: {
                            fillColor: '#FF9400',
                            fillOpacity:0.1,
                            radius: 8,
                            lineColor: null,
                            lineWidth: 3
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Projects',
            color: '#2CC970',
            data: graphData,
            marker: {
                 radius: 6,
                 symbol: "circle",
                 fillColor: '#D3F4E2',
                 fillOpacity:0.1,                 
                 lineWidth: 2,
                 lineColor: null
             },
            events: {
                  click: function (event) { 
                   if(event.point.id != 0)                                      
                       graphDotClicked(event.point.x, event.point.y, event.point.name);                                         
                  }
              }

        }]
```

Comment: You have to use renderer http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.rect to render rect with the desired size. Create the fiddle/paste your code to receive more specific answer.

Comment: You could also make a series of points of type 'line' and draw your rectangle like that: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/gf7wsoyv/. Depends on your axis setup and other params which you have not provided.

Comment: yeah I've gone through it, but the problem is that i need to plot band in that rectangle which is created after intersecting of lines, which may varies as per condition so for that i need co-ordinates of x and y axis so that i can plot  band in that position.

Comment: @PrashantDeotale, so you need it filled with some color? If so, then the Renderer is the way to go - note you have to handle size of chart and any resizing as well as the Renderer does not use the chart's x/y coordinates - it uses the highcharts rendered SVG coordinates.

Comment: I would personally approach this with a `polygon` series: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/polygon